# How to update attribute table layout in QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer

I have selected some columns from attribute table in print composer linked to layer A.
[image]

But when I open my layout in another project with that same layer A, it doesn't refresh/update

[image: refreshing error]

and I have to select columns again. Is there a solution to avoid this operation?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I'm confused:  What do you mean by ***"... selected some columns..."***?  How are you using those columns?  Please edit your question with additional detail.  Screenshots will also help.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @StuSmith, I edited my post with image fo "columns/attributes selection" in qgis print composer.